# sum of counts in a group

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum

I have got the following query, which shows me a 0 or 1 if they entered fields in their profile.

```
select id, 
    count(users.firstname),
    count(users.lastname),
    count(users.gender),
    count(users.country),
    count(users.address_one),
    count(users.city),
    count(users.zipcode),
    count(users.housenumber),
    count(users.phonenumber),
    count(users.educationlevel_id)
from users
group by id;
```

How do I sum all the counts of this and group it by id?

```
select id, SUM(
    count(users.firstname)+ 
    count(users.lastname)+ 
    count(users.gender)+
    count(users.country)+
    count(users.address_one)+
    count(users.city)+
    count(users.zipcode)+
    count(users.housenumber)+
    count(users.phonenumber)+
    count(users.educationlevel_id)
    ) as smartbio_check
from users
group by id, smartbio_check;
```

this query doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `count` values:

```
select id, 
    count(users.firstname) +
    count(users.lastname) +
    count(users.gender) +
    count(users.country) +
    count(users.address_one) +
    count(users.city) +
    count(users.zipcode) +
    count(users.housenumber) +
    count(users.phonenumber) +
    count(users.educationlevel_id) as smartbio_check
from users
group by id
```

Comment: You're my godsend saviour. Sometimes thinking simple is quite hard when you're trying your best to solve a (for my perspective) hard problem